# Symfony 5 - Login form admin section, endless redirecting loop

Tags: php, symfony

My symfony webapp shall have an admin section, that is secured by an authenticator (AdminAuthenticator.php).

I configured this section like this in security.yaml:

```
security:
[...]
    firewalls:
[...]
        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin/
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\AdminAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: admin_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                target: front_home
[...]
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

The redirect to the form works, but when the form should be shown, I get this log:

```
Apr 17 14:57:10 |DEBUG| PHP    127.0.0.1:37778 Accepted path="/usr/bin/php7.4" php="7.4.4"
Apr 17 14:57:10 |INFO | REQUES Matched route "admin_login". method="GET" request_uri="http://lolhub.local:50004/admin/login" route="admin_login" route_parameters={"_controller":"App\\Controller\\Admin\\LoginController::login","_route":"admin_login"}
Apr 17 14:57:10 |DEBUG| SECURI Checking for guard authentication credentials. authenticators=1 firewall_key="admin"
Apr 17 14:57:10 |DEBUG| SECURI Checking support on guard authenticator. authenticator="App\\Security\\AdminAuthenticator"
Apr 17 14:57:10 |DEBUG| SECURI Guard authenticator does not support the request. 
Apr 17 14:57:10 |INFO | SECURI An AuthenticationException was thrown; redirecting to authentication entry point. 
Apr 17 14:57:10 |DEBUG| SECURI Calling Authentication entry point. 
Apr 17 14:57:10 |DEBUG| PHP    127.0.0.1:37778 Closing
```

These are the routes:

```
  admin_home_index             ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/                            
  admin_login                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/login                       
  admin_logout                 ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/logout
```

And this is a part of the AdminAuthenticator.php:

```
class AdminAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'admin_login';

[...]

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }
[...]
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('admin_home_index'));
        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        // throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }
[...]
}
```

I thought `- { path: ^/admin/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }` would prevent the firewall, from blocking the request for the login form.

How can I tell symfony, not to secure the login form, so that I can login, before he checks if I am authenticated?

Comment: Post more details by words which will explain your problem more clear instead of posting  lines of code.Be precise and provide only relative code which may seek attention of people and help you out in better way

Comment: I hope, this is better explained now. I really cracked down the config and code to its essentail parts and explained more with text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the line with `anonymous: lazy # or` null

```
    security:
      [...]
          firewalls:
      [...]
              admin:
                  pattern: ^/admin/
    +             anonymous: lazy # or null
                  guard:
                      authenticators:
                          - App\Security\AdminAuthenticator
                  logout:
                      path: admin_logout
                      # where to redirect after logout
                      target: front_home
```